# VB.Net converting string to bytes then to chinese characters

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding

How do I convert a string to bytes then to chinese characters?
I have the following code, of course it is erreonous I am just so stuck on how to do this:

```
Public Function convertToChinese(ByVal data As String)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Dim chinese As String = Nothing

    For Each C As Char In data
        Dim s = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
        For Each u As Char In s.ToCharArray
            j *= 2
            If C = "1"c Then j += 1
            i += 1
            If i = 8 Then
                i = 0
                chinese &= Char.ConvertFromUtf32(j)
                j = 0
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return chinese
End Function
```

Comment: This is really unclear, what is in `data`?  If its not already a representation of Chinese what is it?

Comment: @AlexK. Say a string like "Andrea" that i would want transformed into chinese characters. I am not sure it is possible...is it?